# track open email in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

To track the openings of an email, does marketing cloud do it for me automatically or do I have to insert the snippet with  for each email every time?

" The tracking feature uses a 1x1 pixel transparent GIF image to track information. The pixel is automatically inserted into every email unless you're using an HTML-Paste template "

If i create email without HTML paste template, i can not put <custom name= "opencounter" type= tracking">?

Comment: Usually it is part of the email template you chose. Then you create an email based on that template and you will always have the "open tracking" in it.

Comment: The answer is in your question: "The pixel is automatically inserted into every email unless you're using an HTML-Paste template." So, if you don't use HTML-Paste template, the pixel is already there.

Comment: thank u, because my client also uses the spippet with templates, and I didn't understand why.

Answer (score 3):

All of the default templates for HTML email that SF has automatically have the open pixel inside of them. If you use your custom built templates or html-paste email, giving yourself full control on the code, you will need to insert this manually.

Also as a note, this pixel will not appear in your text version or text only emails at all, since there can be no images in a text only email.

To answer your ask of why they might use it inside the templates - it could be:

- A failsafe to ensure the pixel is there. To keep their content team in the habit of adding it in so that if they use custom templates, they can ensure the open tracking still exists.
- They can be using custom built templates that do not have the open pixel included
- They do not know that the pixel is automatically included in the templates and are doing so thinking that it is required.

Comment: Thank u so much Gortonington. is the same for clicks?

Comment: Clicks is a setting when creating the job. By default it is on, but can be turned off.